# JS Fiddle print/alert

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Update. No problem with this question. See first comment.

I`m trying to figure out this code with jsfiddle.net, but when I run it, it triggers the actual printer attached to my computer. I changed print to "alert" http://jsfiddle.net/eZ3jQ/ and it returned (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3).  However, as the return calls find, I expected it to run find over again.

Is there a way I can get the program to keep running?

```
function findSequence(goal) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == goal)
      return history;
    else if (start > goal)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

print(findSequence(24));
```

Comment: I'm confused, what do you want it to keep on running, ain't (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3) = 24 ? As in the target? I might have understood your code wrong.

Comment: oops, you`re right. Thanks. I got confused.

Comment: You made me chuckle. *thumbsup*

Answer (score 10):

Well, apart from the fix that wasn't needed, lemme make a suggestion.

**HTML**

```
<div id="logs"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var logs=document.getElementById('logs');
function logIt(msg){
    var e=document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML=msg;
    logs.insertBefore(e,logs.firstChild);
}
```

Log function that prepends messages, useful so you can keep track of things. Alert is nasty :P

Comment: Or, if you are using a browser which can handle it (Firefox+Firebug, Chrome, Safari, etc.) use `console.log()` and it's siblings. Very nice for discrete logging and error recording, especially in a development environment.

Comment: I find firebug to be a must for development, I have met people that disregard it entirely. In the end, all web development is 80% IE issues and that's where console.log isn't useful :D

Comment: I think that IE8 now has a port of Firebug called "Developer Tools". Plus there is Firebug Lite, which runs in nearly anything. Meaning `console.log()` is slowly becoming universal, more or less.

Comment: If you want the log to append messages, change `logs.insertBefore(e, logs.firstChild)` to `logs.appendChild(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="log"></div>
```

JS:

```
var log = function(msg) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('log');
    elem.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>';
};
```